# Reducing space between backreference and entry in bibliography

Tags: natbib, back-referencing

is it possible to reduce the space between "page" and the bibliography entry? A negative vspace is to unreliable.

Answer: `\hfill` does the trick

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{nohyperref}
\usepackage[pageref]{backref}

\renewcommand*{\backref}[1]{}
\renewcommand*{\backrefalt}[4]{
    \ifcase #1 (Not cited.)
    \or         \hfill(page~#2.)
    \else   \\(pages~#2.)%
   \fi
}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\begin{document}

\citep{brown1960}

\bibliography{sources}

\end{document}
```

sources.bib

```
@incollection{brown1960,
  title={The Pronouns of Power and Solidarity},
  author={Brown, Roger and Gilman, Albert},
  booktitle={Style in Language},
  editor={Sebeok, Thomas A.},
  pages={253–76},
  publisher={MIT Press},
  address={Cambridge},
  year={1960}
}
```

Comment: I don't understand this. Is the line "Answer: `\hfill` does the trick" an answer to the question? If so, please delete it from the question and add a proper, complete answer. If not, then explain clearly what seems to be the problem.